# How to control python code though web page

Tags: raspbian, python, web, html5

Currently I am working on a dual axis sun calibration device. Everything was going well so far but I made a huge mistake.

Here is what I made so far.

I wrote my code in Python 3.8. Libraries I used:

- Astropy (sun position calculation)
- RPi.GPIO (GPIO control to control stepper motor drivers)
  There are two classes. The following is a short description of them.
- Numpy (store and save sun position arrays)
- Matplotlib (drawing and saving graphs with time and sun position as data)

First class is responsible for:

- stepper motor movement
- stepper motor movement calculations (how many steps to move by X degrees)
- auto-home on both axes (set position to absolute zero)
- keeping track of current position of both axes
- calibrate both axes accordingly to calculated sun position array
- calibrate automaticly every X minutes (where X is the frequency that can be changed)

Second class:

- calculates sun position (altitude-azimuth) for entire day and saves data in numpy array
- drawing and saving graphs using date and sun position as data
- calculates sun position current time for instantaneous calibration
- find sunrise, culumination and sunset

Here you can see how the device works so far. It's a timelapse mode to show how both axes move: [Dual axis sun calibration device. Time-lapse mode](https://youtu.be/YfH81y3EOzs)

The mistake I made is that I didn't write my code with networking in mind. What I want to do is a webpage to remote control the device.

Webpage should do the following:

- display current axes positon (both altitude and azimuth)
- display current calibration frequency
- display sun position graph (graph is stored on RPi memory)
- move both axes to absolute zero
- change calibration frequency

Now I am stuck. Could you point me in the right direction what should I do next? What libraries or frameworks would you reccomend for such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a framework like [Flask](https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/flask/). With that you can create a webserver with only a few lines of code. And because it is written in python, you can use the classes you created already :)

Comment: I'm checking it out right now. Seems like a good place to start. Thank you!